# My website won't scroll down to see all the content, how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, css-grid

I'm using CSS Grid for my first website and I've started to add content but I can't scroll down and the content just goes off the page. I've tried to change the view-height but I can't seem to fix it. Can anyone look at my code and help me fix this problem, thanks.

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Student Hacks</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body class="grid">

<header>
<img class="logo" href="index.html" src="img/student-hacks-logo.png" alt="Logo">
</header>

<div class="menu" id="menu-toggle"></div>
<nav id="menu-nav">
  <a class="home" href="index.html">HOME</a>
  <a class="money" href="money.html">MONEY</a>
  <a class="study" href="study.html">STUDY</a>
  <a class="faqs" href="faqs.html">FAQs</a>
</nav>

<main>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="img/students.jpg" alt="image ofstudents">
    <div class="text">Welcome To Student Hacks</div>
  </div>

  <hr class="index-hr-1">

  <h2 class="heading">Who Are We?</h2>
  <p class="about-us-text">Student Hacks is a site based towards students
  looking for quick tips and tricks to make their
    student lives easier. We provide money tips, as
    well as revision tips.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
  <p class="footer-writing">Student Hacks 2018©</p>
</footer>

<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

It could be an issue to do with the grid-template-rows but I'm not sure.

```
/* MOBILE AND GLOBAL STYLES */

/* applies to screens smaller than 500px (first 
breakpoint) */
/* and above unless overwritten below */

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: black;
      }
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 10vh 12vh 75vh 5vh;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "menu"
    "content"
    "footer";
}
header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: #e5e5e5;
}
.logo {
    width: 350px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
nav {
  grid-area: menu;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 12vh;
}
nav a {
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
  background: #bfbfbf;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: #dfd;
  background: #7d8687;
}
.menu {
  background: #555;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 2em;
}
.menu-toggle {
  display: flex;
}
.home {
  height: 3vh;
}
.money {
  height: 3vh;
}
.study {
  height: 3vh;
}
.faqs {
  height: 3vh;
}
main {
  grid-area: content;
  /* increasing the height of one element increases 
  all row heights */
  /*height: 25vh;*/
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.text {
  color: #94FCDD;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 4px 2px 2px #000;
}
footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: #e5e5e5;
}
.footer-writing {
  text-align: center;
}
.accordion {
  background-color: #94FCDD;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #399A7C;
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  text-align: center;
}
.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.faq-hr-1 {
  /* border: dashed 1.5px;
  width: 35%;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  margin-top: 35px; */
  height: 10px;
  border: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px #8c8b8b inset;
}
.index-hr-1 {
  height: 10px;
  border: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 12px -10px #8c8b8b inset;
}
.about-us-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
/* TABLET STYLES */

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {

  /* applies to screens wider than 499px */

  body {
    background: white;
  }
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    /*grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;*/
    /*or set the rows to 'view height (vh)'*/
    grid-template-rows: 17vh 3vh 75vh 5vh;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header  header  header"
      "menu    menu    menu"
      "content content content"
      "footer  footer  footer";
  }
  nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    line-height: 1.5em;
  }
  /* just change the menu colours on hover above 
mobile widths */
  nav a:hover {
  color: #dfd;
  background: #7d8687;
}
  .logo {
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
}
  .container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}
  .text {
    color: #94FCDD;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 4px 2px 2px #000;
  }
}

/* DESKTOP STYLES */

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

  /* applies to screens wider than 999px */

  body {
    background: white;
  }
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    /*grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;*/
    /*or set the rows to 'view height (vh)'*/
    grid-template-rows: 17vh 3vh 75vh 5vh;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header  header  header"
      "menu    menu    menu"
      "content content content"
      "footer  footer  footer";
  }
  .container img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
  }
  .text {
    top: 50%;
  }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
//JS for accordion on faq's page
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.toggle("active");
  var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
  if (panel.style.maxHeight){
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
  } else {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
});
```

}

Comment: You remove `overflow: hidden;` from `body { ... }` in your CSS. Note `grid-template-rows: 10vh 12vh 75vh 5vh;` should sum up to `100vh`.

Comment: Also, don't set your header and footer's height in `vh`. To understand why, view your page on a phone. And then rotate it.

Comment: Would you suggest not to use vh? What is the best unit to use for height?

Comment: Let me put it this way: How many websites have you seen changing `height` of menu, header or footer based on viewport height? `px` is the most common unit for their height. You might want to use `em` or `rem` if it's font related. But most modern layouts do not specify a `height` for these items. All you need is `min-height: 100vh` on your page container, really. Header, menu and footer should not be squeezable and `<main>` should be the only element growing when there's extra height available. That's the principle.

Comment: I now understand a lot more, thanks for taking time out to explain that to me, I really appreciate it. I'm new to web development so thanks for being patient!

Comment: Here's a ["holy grail"](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/oy18xz2u/). It's just a starter, but it's pointing in the right direction, IMHO. Put some more conent in each element and you'll see it behaves well on all devices. Good luck!